# Did I produce a broken question?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I wrote a question: **How is a one-hot code called, if zero is acepted, too?**, which is listed on EE.SE, but I can't open it.

As I clicked `submit` in the Android app, the connection had an error.

Is my question defect?

Comment: If [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/216554/7036) is the question in question, it doesn't look broken.  I can see it alright.

Comment: I think it's working again. Shall I remove this meta question?

Comment: Let's leave it for the anomaly reporting sake.